# "internet in browsers" or "internet on browsers"?

Tags: prepositions

Tell me please which sentence sounds the most natural.

> My mobile internet doesn't work **in** any browser, but it works **in** some apps.
>
> My mobile internet doesn't work **on** any browser, but it works **on** some apps.

If both sentences don't sound well, then what would the most natural way to say it?

Comment: I wouldn't say either of your prepositions is "wrong", but personally I'd prefer *...doesn't work **with** any browser*. BTW, it's *doesn't sound **good***, not ***well***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that these actually depend a bit on how you conceptualize "the internet" and where it is and how you access it! And different people have somewhat different conceptions of that so we end up with language that's not in practice standardized across common usage.

You're treading an area where prepositions are a bit fuzzy in making the transition from physical to virtual senses, and multiple versions can sound OK (or not). In this case, since I think you're trying to say *"I can't seem to access the internet using the browser on my phone, but I can access it using some apps"*, I might formulate it more succinctly like:

```
The mobile internet doesn't work in any of my browsers, but does work in some apps.
```

It also sounds OK to me to talk about the mobile internet **on** a browser (or in, or within, or using, a browser), but sounds less OK to talk about the mobile internet **on an app**. But I don't know that I'd describe those alternatives as "incorrect."